# CodeBlocks not finding wxWidgets

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

I'm on PopOS and installed wxWidgets via the terminal when I first got the error [`error: wx/wxprec.h: No such file or directory`](https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=19402.0) as said by the user "oBFusCATed". I did not manually compile from source.

`wx-config --version` outputs `3.0.5`

`wx-config --cxxflags` outputs:

```
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.0 -I/usr/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread
```

`wx-config --libs` outputs:

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread   -lwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_html-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_qa-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0
```

I created my project via the wizard and made sure I selected the same version (`wxWidgets 3.0.x`).

In the step that says "Please select your favorite GUI Builder to use.", I chose `wxSmith` and `Frame based` options.

In the next step, which prompts me to choose a compiler, I left it as it was (see image below).

[image: compiler]

In the next step, which prompts me to select the wxWidgets configuration I selected the following options:

[image: wxWidgets_configuration]

Though, I also tried using the `Use default wxWidgets configuration` and without any `Other Options` selected.

And last, I clicked **Finish**.

In Code::Blocks I've added the `` `wx-config --cxxflags` `` and `` `wx-config --libs` `` (even two additional ones but with the full path which the commands above return in the terminal), as you can see in the image below.

[image: flags]

In the **Other compiler options**, I have these two lines (which I did not add myself - must've been the wizard):

```
-Winvalid-pch
-include wx_pch.h
```

I even added the output of `wx-config --cxxflags` to **Other resource compiler options**.

I also added a Global Variable `wx` with this base path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx` (copy/pasted), as mentioned in [step #7 here](https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=WxWindowsQuickRef). If I put the name of the variable exactly as `$(#wx)`, it appears as `set___wx__` instead of just `wx`, as seen in some other instructions I've found here and on other forums/guides.

Interestingly enough, if I click the button on the right to navigate to it, *there is no `wx` folder*. Like, it's nowhere to be found. If I were to use my normal file manager, I can navigate to it (terminal works as well). Could this have something to do with it?

In the **Linker Settings** tab, I've added these two libraries:

[image: linker_settings]

At the end of it all, I still get the error mentioned at the beginning. If I were to comment out that line, I get the same error but for `wx/app.h` and `wx/frame.h`, which made me think that it's just not finding the wxWidgets, but I can't figure out why.

This is the first time I'm using C++/Code::Blocks/wxWidgets, so if you give me any instructions where I need to put stuff, please, try to be specific.

P.S. Many of the guides on how to set this up seem to be for Windows and the only one I found for Ubuntu (since PopOS is based on it) is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0TDnnlyscM). Where he even gets the same error, but his solution did not work (add the output of `wx-config --cxxflags` to **Other resource compiler options** - which I've already tried - though, he does build from source).

P.S.2. I found [this setup build which uses the binary download option](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Using_wxWidgets_Pre-Built_Binary_in_CodeBlocks), but it's for Windows. Would something mess up if I were to attempt it?

P.S.3. I know a lot of people have similar issues, but the stuff I've already tried seem to have solved their problem and since for me it didn't, I figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

*Son of a motherless goat* >_<

The moment I ask, an idea popped into my head from another issue I had recently.

I had installed Code::Blocks via the PopShop (i.e. flatpak) and that flatpak had no access to the `wx` folder, which is why it wouldn't show up when trying to navigate to it via Code::Blocks.

I uninstalled it and installed it again via `sudo apt install codeblocks`. I created a new project via the wizard (it wouldn't let me select `wxSmith` because it doesn't seem to come with it - `wxSmith plugin is not loaded can not continue`) with the same wizard settings mentioned in my original post.

Then I only added the `wx-config --cxxflags` and `wx-config --libs` compiler flags and it built!

Darn it, Flatpak...

Anyway, for people that are interested in adding `wxSmith` plugin, the person in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gSdTrJM_zM) shows how.

Run `sudo apt install codeblocks-contrib` in your terminal and if you had Code::Blocks open, make sure to restart it - and perhaps give the dude a like if the video is still up! :3

Comment: most, if not all, *nix-based OSes use dynamic libraries all around. Very rarely they are using static builds. Please make sure you check you wizard configuration as you said you use distro-based library and you didn't compile it yourself.